# Change GPS location without mock locations or root

Tags: android, android-gps

Is there any way to change/fake the GPS location without using mock locations or root?

I know that for mock locations you need to enable and disable mock locations fast so other apps can't detect. Whoever that requires root. How could I do that without it?

Comment: "Is there any way to change/fake the GPS location without using mock locations or root?" -- I sure hope not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why not?

Comment: For blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. Malware authors would *love* the ability to manipulate other apps by providing fake location information (e.g., trigger geofences at the wrong time, steer the driver using a navigation app off a bridge).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yhea...

Comment: "enable and disable mock locations fast so other apps can't detect", sadly, the created location's isFromMockProvider method will tell you the truth.

Comment: @Blackkara I saw that thing of disabling and enabling fast on com.alexa.fakegps decompiled apk. At least pokemon go doesn't detect with it.

Comment: Maybe it could, but doesn't change the possibilities of detecting ways of mock location and "allow mock locations" option.